# Send event to angular directive function in scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a directive with angular for displaying a multiselect that loads its options into a template with an ajax call.
Here is my directive for now:

```
function AngularMultiselect () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'temp.html',
        scope: {
            tipo: "@"
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            scope.open_tab = function(){
                element.addClass('open');
                $(document).on("click",function(){ //beign called at the same time
                    console.log("document clicked");
                });
            };
            console.log('multiselect being called');

        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<filtro tipo="client"></filtro>
```

Inside the template:

```
<button type="button"
        class="multiselect btn"
        ng-click="open_tab()">
```

The problem I have is that the tab opens and closes at the same click. I would use the event to stop the propagation of the event but I'm not able to send it... I've tryed `open_tab($event)` but then `$event` contains `'client'`. Any ideas?

Here you can see it working: http://codepen.io/vandervals/pen/VeZrdV

Comment: Could you do a live demo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just defer the document click handler attach to avoid this issue :

instead of :

```
scope.open_tab = function(){
                element.addClass('open');
                $(document).on("click",function(){ //beign called at the same time
                    console.log("document clicked");
                });
            };
```

just do :

```
scope.open_tab = function(){
  element.addClass('open');
  $timeout(function() {
    $(document).on("click",function(){ //no longer beign called at the same time
      console.log("document clicked");
    });
  }, 1, false);
};
```

To avoid the initial click event to trigger the second handler

Comment: Works only the first time

Comment: Yea, you also need to unbind the document handler after triggering it (which you probably dont do), else you will bind it multiple time.